# How to get connection string without DbOptions?

Tags: .net, connection-string, blobstorage

I'm a project that doesn't need DbContext class, and I'm using BlobStorage DB on appsettings.json

This is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "StorageConnectionString": "Connection"
 }
```

and I configure on Startup.cs class, without options, because I don't need DbContext right now

```
_configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageConnectionString");
```

But I need to call my connection string on my BlobStorageService class without pass connection string name (because is already on appsettings.json).

The question is: How I can call connectionString on Service class without pass the connection string name?

Comment: Returns null. It works if I use Configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageConnectionString"); but I need to get IConfiguration and do a dependency injection inside my BlobStorageService, and I have done this job on Startup.class already.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use

```
 Configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageConnectionString");
```

Getting IConfiguration and doing dependency injection inside my BlobStorageService.

Answer (score 0):

How are you registering your `BlobStorageService`? If you're already retrieving your connection string within `Startup.cs`, you can always register your `BlobStorageService` with a string dependency to be used within the service at runtime.

In your `BlobStorageService`, you can require a string to be injected when the service is requested:

```
public class BlobStorageService : IBlobStorageService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public BlobStorageService(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;

        // Do whatever storage client initialization is required by the SDK...
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Startup.cs`, register your dependency with the connection string you've already retrieved at application startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var yourConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageConnectionString");
            
    // Register with the appropiate service lifetime
    services.AddTransient<IBlobStorageService>(_ => new BlobStorageService(yourConnectionString));

    // ...other dependencies
}
```

Comment: So, I'm using azure blobs and service bus services. How can I do that with more than one ConnectionString? (Each service provides a specific primary connection).